# Windows 7 license - move from 32bit to 64bit with OEM key with Lenovo

Tags: windows-7, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

[Can I use a Windows 7 Professional 32-Bit OEM licence to install the 64-Bit version, too?](https://superuser.com/questions/73327/can-i-use-a-windows-7-professional-32-bit-oem-licence-to-install-the-64-bit-versi)

This questions asks it generically, but does anybody know specifically about Lenovo outlet computers?

I want to buy an outlet computer with Windows 7 Home Premium 32, but I would rather have Windows Home Premium 64.  Can I use the license I am getting with the outlet laptop to do a clean install of the 64bit version.  I know I can't upgrade, I want to do this first thing out of the box when I get the computer.

It seems like it is possible, according to the [answer.microsoft.com](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7install/thread/66896cf8-2693-40ca-9051-da1fde1922c6) the key will work for 64bit or 32bit.

Comment: Ask the OEM to ship it with the x64 version?

Comment: Outlet store.  No changes possible.  I want to save $300 from the outlet, but if I can't get the OS I want I will have to customize one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of people who have done this with ASUS branded laptops.

I don't see why it would be any different for any other brand.

I'm pretty sure the key is tied to the product version not down to the 32/64 bit version.  As long as you install the same version, ie., Upgrade from Windows Home Premium 32bit to 
Windows Home Premium 64bit you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

This [guide](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=144783) is for vista but the method should be similar for windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Trip Report:

New latptop came with Windows 7 pro 32bit installed.

[I went through this guide](http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=144783) and it was pretty accurate.

1. Make backups of the supplied swtools folder with all the drivers and programe.
2. Used the [ABR utility](http://directedge.us/content/abr-activation-backup-and-restore) (Activation Backup and Restore) to extract the windows authentication tokens
3. Ripped an ISO of my Windows 7 Home Premium disc
4. Used this [eicfg utility](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/11/01/create-windows-7-universal-iso-with-all-editions-selection-on-install-with-ei-cfg-removal-utility/) to edit the ISO so it will show a menu to let me select which version of Windows 7
5. Installed Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, but I didn't type in my product key
6. Use the ABR utility again to active my new 64bit OS
7. Installed Thinkvantage update utility to get all my drivers back.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I wanted to make this clear - MS license agreement allows you to switch no problem from the OEM.  The best method is just to call Lenovo and tell them you want to order product recovery disks for the 64-bit version, they sell them to you for around $50 shipped.